# Latex Compilation from Gedit External Tools Using $HOME folder based Texlive

Tags: gedit, latex, texlive

I relocated /usr/local/texlive(2020) to $HOME folder and renamed "/usr/share/texlive" to disable its effects.

The latex file gets compiled successfully from command prompt but not from "gedit external tools".

```
#!/bin/sh

file=${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%}

latex $file
```

Instead, i obtained output as

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!   
    /home/username/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/username/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt line 25.
    I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

Somehow gedit still using pdflatex from default texlive version(2019) in ubuntu. Secondly it is not compiling successfully. Kindly guide me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Well I just uninstalled texlive-base and gedit automatically recognizes texlive from its set path. Wow it was that simple.
I wonder why does texlive-base prevents gedit from compiling from the path set for other texlive versions.